# Everybody else has a rep of 101. Why not me ?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I see a lot of people on BCG have a reputation of 101, with no answers, no votes, no questions, and only one badge, the Autobiographer.

I have made answers, I got votes, and I earned the Autobiographer and three other badges ; my rep is still at 81 (at the moment I'm posting this).

Can you explain ?

(Note : I'm not whining, I'm not losing sleep over my rep, I'm just trying to understand if something about the site has eluded me so far. ;))

Comment: I'm tempted to lobby for a larger increase if you have one site over, say, 20,000.  <lie type="transparent">I'm not just saying that because I have one account over 20,000!</lie>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus)

You need to earn 200 rep on any SE site, then any other site that you link to that account gets +100 rep.

This is why a lot of people start with 101 rep.  Essentially the system guarantees that if you've become minimally trusted (>200 rep) on any site then you deserve to be advanced past the opening jitters on any new site.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just under the 200 mark on SO, so I may get the bonus here sometimes.